# save 'top' cpu/mem out put into files

Tags: bash, shell, cpu-usage

I am new to shell scripts.   I wrote below script to save 'top' command's output into files:  cpu.csv and mem.csv.  But the files were not created.  Any error in my script below:

```bash
#!/bin/bash


TIMESTAMP=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S")

top -b -n 1 &

CPU_LINE=$(grep "Cpu(s)")
MEM_LINE=$(grep "KiB Mem")

echo "$TIMESTAMP,$CPU_LINE" >> cpu.csv

echo "$TIMESTAMP,$MEM_LINE" >> mem.csv
```

I expect to see the 'top' command's "Cpu(s)" line been saved into cpu.csv file with the timestamp up front.

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Why would you expect that? You aren't doing anything to direct top's output into the input of the later grep commands.

Comment: It would be much more efficient to read `/proc/meminfo` and `/proc/loadavg` directly, instead of having `top` read them _and hundreds of other procfs files besides_ (assuming you're on a system with a significant number of running processes) and then throwing away almost all the data that top has collected to extract only the few pieces you care about.

Comment: (There are other tools, such as `vmstat`, you might take a look at as well; no reason to overcollect and filter when you could choose a tool that monitors only what you care about).

Comment: Thanks, @CharlesDuffy.  I will look into the tools you suggested.   I am new to Linux in general...  learning.  Great suggestions.

Comment: BTW, many copies of top print a timestamp as part of their output. If the one you're using is onesuch, then you could arguably have a _continuous_ pipeline `top | awk` with awk splitting the output of top's polling operations into the output files without any `date` command, and without needing to restart `top` every time you want to add a line to each of your files. I would generally consider that style of approach ideal.

Comment: I see the timestamp on the 'top' output first line, but it only has hh:mm:ss part, no date part, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use awk to extract the two items you want in a single pass, emitting them in a well-known order -- like this:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' cpu_line mem_line < <(
  top -b -n 1 | awk '
    /Cpu[(]s[)]/ { cpu_line=$0 }
    /KiB Mem/    { mem_line=$0 }
    END { print(cpu_line); print(mem_line); printf("\0"); }
  '
)
```

...though in your particular case you don't need to read the data into shell variables at all, and can have awk directly write to your output files; if you're using *GNU* awk it can also do `date`'s work internally:

```
top -b -n 1 | gawk '
  BEGIN { timestamp = strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S") }
  /Cpu[(]s[)]/ { printf("%s,%s\n", timestamp, $0) >> "cpu.csv" }
  /KiB Mem/    { printf("%s,%s\n", timestamp, $0) >> "mem.csv" }
'
```

Note that the first example above (the one with `<( ... )` syntax) requires that your script be run with *bash*, not sh. (Also, the use of lower-case variable names is deliberate: all-caps names are used for variables that reflect or modify shell behavior, whereas the POSIX standard reserves names with at least one lower-case character for application-defined use; see the relevant standard at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, @Charles Duffy.  The second block of script worked so well and efficient.  It's just what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Your grep command is incomplete. You will need to apply your pattern against something, normally a file or from standard input.

You can connect the standard output from one command to the standard input of another by piping `|` the two commands.

For example:

```
CPU_LINE=$(top -b -n 1 | grep "Cpu(s)")
```

This would create the CPU_LINE variable with the data you were expecting, to then output to your file.

Comment: This is correct as far as it goes, but it's quite deeply suboptimal to run top twice, rather than to run it _once_ and use the output twice.

Comment: Thank you, @hznat,  it helps.  At least it got back the result.

Comment: @Charles Duffy, yeah.  I would love to know how to run 'top' command once and extract its output twice to get CPU and memory.  Any suggestion or link?  Many thanks!